# Powershell Invoke-GPUpdate - "No Logoff" possible?

Tags: powershell

Looking to run `Invoke-GPUPdate -force` to a group of remote computers and respond to the logoff prompt with "No".

Tried:

```
Echo "n" | invoke-gpupdate
```

> Error:Invoke-gpupdate does not accept pipeline input

Command Used:

```
Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $computer -RandomDelayInMinutes 0 -force
```

[image: Picture of Logoff response to GPUpdate]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like this cmdlet initiates/schedules a run of gpupdate that ends up happening separately (out of process), so there isn't much to do via PowerShell's standard ways of dealing with something like that, since the prompt doesn't come from within PowerShell. There's a `-LogOff` parameter, but it's a switch parameter which implies that its value is meant to be used just for *doing* the logoff. You can try it this way: `-Logoff:$false` but most likely it won't work to get rid of the prompt.

I think your best chance is not to use this cmdlet, but to instead use `Invoke-Command` with `gpupdate.exe` directly:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    echo nn | gpupdate.exe /force
}
```

But this requires that PowerShell remoting is enabled on the machines you want to manage.